# How to insert into semi sorted List?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pseudocode

I have a large semi sorted list of Strings sorted by only first character. Each String is accompanied by an ID. The first x entries start with letter A then follow entries starting with letter B and so on. Not all letters are necesarily represented.
By semi sorted I mean that there are exceptions (wrongly sorted entries). It is NOT possible to sort the entries in a correct fashion. Already existent entries have to remain at their ID.

I have crafted the follwing example only including starting letters A and B. The entries starting with C, Z and S have been wrongly entered.

Example:

```
| ID   | NAME |
|------|------|
| 6000 | AXXX |
| 6001 | AXZS |
| 6003 | AAFD |
| 6004 | CSDF |
| 6005 | ZSSF |
| 6006 | ASDF |
| 6007 | BXAS |
| 6010 | BZDS |
| 6011 | SHZF |
| 6012 | BHZT |
```

I want to add entries to the list. A entry with a Name starting with letter A should be inserted grouped with other entries starting with letter A if possible or otherwise at the very end.

In the above example a entry with a Name starting with letter A should be inserted with ID 6002.
A entry with a Name starting with letter B should be added with ID 6008.

I am not sure how to solve this. My first thoughts are to first iterate over the existing list starting with the lowest ID and to save information on the letter group. 
Like:
`Letter: A StartID: 6000 EndID: 6006  IsFull:False` 
`Letter: B StartID: 6007 EndID: 6012  IsFull:False`

And then when it comes to inserting using the above information for the determination of possible IDs of the new entry. After inserting a new entry this information would have to be updated.

However I am not sure on how to exactly achieve this. All I need is some pseudo code for a possible solution so I can write my own code.

Comment: You do not appear to have even attempted to write your own pseudo code.

Comment: I have tried, but miserably failed. Basically I don't really have a clue on how to deal with entries that are wrongly sorted.

Comment: The "wrongly sorted" part of this really messes things up.  I can't think of a way to find an insertion point other than iterating the entire list to find the first or last matching entry.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a few steps

- find the position of the insertion group if it exists (what if the first few were `B`, `Z`, before `A`?)
- find the last member of the group if it exists, otherwise the last member of the prior group (for example when inserting `F`)
- determine if there's room before in the left index after the last member of the group, and before the first member of the next one
- if a position exists for insertion, insert the value, else

  - find the last position
  - append the value

Some considerations

- you must keep track of and consider several positions, some structure will help you with this
- if you have runs ordered `A`,`B`,`Z`,`C` in the left column, does the block with Z comprise a group? is the block C misplaced? otherwise it seems your values should grow wherever the first new member is
- "next" needs to consider multiple characters (presumably `ABAA` comes after `AABB`)